# Find and replace float numbers on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, replace

I have some big numpy lists (thousands of elements) that have specific values, e.g. one of the values must be one of those: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0.

I need to find and replace some of these values, and what I want is to do this with minimum computational cost. Is there a way to do it without looping on each element?

Here is what I got until now:

```
for x, y in np.ndindex(z_.shape):
    z_[x,y] = 150.0 if z_[x,y] == 1.0 else z_[x,y]
    z_[x,y] = 120.0 if z_[x,y] == 2.0 else z_[x,y]
    z_[x,y] = 110.0 if z_[x,y] == 3.0 else z_[x,y]
```

Can I generalize these if to pass a list of values, making this portion of the function more general?

Comment: If I understood correctly you could use a mask

Comment: @DanielMesejo can you please show an example, link or doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.select`:

```
z_ = np.select( (z_==1,z_==2, z_==3),
                (150, 120, 110),
                default=z_)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do:

```
import numpy as np

z_ = np.arange(0, 8).reshape((4, 2))

z_[z_ == 1] = 150
z_[z_ == 2] = 120
z_[z_ == 3] = 110

print(z_)
```

**Output**

```
[[  0 150]
 [120 110]
 [  4   5]
 [  6   7]]
```

See [boolean index arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). Although [Quang Hoang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58241860/4001592) seems more appropriate.